# Is an infinite product of entire functions: $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(z)$, a entire function?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, entire-functions

Is it true that "an infinite product of entire functions $\{ f_{n}(z) \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is again an entire function"?

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(z)$$
(entire function is a function which is analytic in the complex plane).

Comment: If it converges locally uniformly, then yes.

Comment: @Lukas: I don't have any further information, I just have an infinite sequence of entire functions and want to see if the product is entire or not. So I understand that it is not true in general!

Comment: Maybe you should post the explicit product you are interested in? In general, like for series there is no reason that these products converge in the whole plane.

Comment: I already did..

Comment: What if $f_n(z)=z$ for all $n$?

Answer (score 6):

Start with a sequence rather than a product.  There is a sequence of polynomials $p_n(z)$ such that $p_n(z) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for every $z \ne 0$ but $p_n(0) = 1$.  These can be obtained using Runge's Theorem so that $|p_n(z)| < 1/n$ on 
$K_n = \{r e^{i\theta}: 1/n \le r \le n, 0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi - 1/n\}$.  Then
if $f_n(z) = \exp(p_n(z) - p_{n-1}(z))$ for $n > 1$ with $f_1(z) = \exp(p_1(z))$, we have 
$\prod_{n=1}^\infty f_n(z) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp(p_n(z)) = 1$ for all $z \ne 0$ but 
$e$ for $z = 0$.  So this infinite product is not analytic, in fact not continuous, at $0$.